# PHP Array not indexing correctly

Tags: php

I have an array (`$myArray`) which looks like this:

```
Array ( 
     [0] => 2001
     [1] => 2002
     [2] => 2003
     [3] => 2004
     [4] => 2005
     [5] => 2006
     [6] => 2007
```

etc etc

When I use

```
$occurences = array_count_values($myArray)
```

I get

```
Array ( 
   [2001] => 5 
   [2002] => 7 
   [2003] => 7 
   [2004] => 7 
   [2005] => 7 
   [2006] => 2 
   [2007] => 6 )
```

When I try to index using

```
echo $occurences[0];
```

I get an error of

> Undefined offset: 0

Comment: Your original array isn't what you think it is. It might be getting changed before you try to access its values.

Comment: you are counting occurences of the values, which returns an **associative** array, each key being the value, and as value the number of times it is found. So it is not a numeric index array. A bit confusing here because your values are integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `foreach()` if you want to loop over your ocurrences array :

```
foreach($occurences as $item) {
   echo $item . '<br>';
}
```

but if you want only the first element, you could use `reset($occurences)`

`reset()` gives you the first value of the array if you have an element inside the array, it also gives you FALSE in case the array is empty.

Answer (score 1):

The keys in the result of `array_count_values` are the values in the input array. So the `[0]` key you're looking for isn't there. You can see in the output

```
Array ( 
   [2001] => 5 
   [2002] => 7 
   [2003] => 7 ...
```

that the first key is `[2001]`.

If you want to get the first item, either explicitly refer to `$occurrences[2001]`, or use

```
echo reset($occurrences);
```

instead if you don't know what the first year will be.

If you want more than just the first element, `$occurrences` can also be iterated with foreach.

```
foreach ($occurrences as $year => $count) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no key name '0' in `$occurences`.

As you can see in the `print_r` of `$occurences` in your question, the keys of that array are the values from `$myarray`.

If you want to print the first value of `$occurences`, you should write :

```
echo $occurences['2001'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) documentation it tells you that the function returns an associative array.

> Returns an associative array of values from array as keys and their count as value.

So you cannot call the `$occurences` array like that.

So from what you explained above, you have the following:

```
<?php
 $myarray = array ( 
   0 => 2001, 
   1 => 2002,
   2 => 2003,
   3 => 2004, 
   4 => 2005, 
   5 => 2006, 
   6 => 2007 );
 
$occurences = array_count_values($myarray);

print_r($occurences);
```

This gives me the following:

```
Array ( [2001] => 1 
        [2002] => 1 
        [2003] => 1 
        [2004] => 1 
        [2005] => 1 
        [2006] => 1 
        [2007] => 1 )
```

Obviously, the values will differ as I guess you have a larger data set in `$myarray`.

If you want to get the value of each of the years, you would do `echo $occurrences['2003'];` which will give you back the value of the year.